# How to (theoretically) capture 59 megajoules of power in 5 seconds to store like a battery for a month?

Tags: energy, power-engineering, battery-storage

On Dec 21, 2021 EUROfusion Scientists in Culham, UK produced 59 megajoules in 5 sustained seconds from their nuclear fusion experiment.

- What theoretically would be required to capture that energy and transmit it into storage?
- What theoretical 'battery' could be made to handle such enormous amounts so fast?
- If it were possible, could it then be drained off slowly for use, say over a month or two?

Comment: That is thermal rather than electrical energy, so you cannot store it in a battery.  You would use it to power a steam turbine which would convert a fraction of it to electrical power and dissipate the rest as waste heat.

Comment: no chemical batteries can do that. the chemical reactions are just to slow. Electric devices which can store energy "superfast" are capacitors.

Comment: Wouldn't you just need to use multiple batteries? If you have one battery that's able to accept 50,000 watts of power, then obviously 1,000 of those batteries would be able to accept 50,000,000 watts of power.

Comment: Inductance would prevent you from getting that amount of energy into a battery that fast. Again, it's thermal energy, not electrical, you'd have to run it through a turbine. I guess you could store the energy in salt or water then use that to generate steam.

Comment: The joule is the unit of energy and not power. Red rag to a bull (like saying the voltage measured was 3 amps)

Comment: It's about 12MW

Comment: 59MJ isn't *that* much energy; it's 23W continuously for one month and wouldn't charge e.g. a Tesla more than a quarter of the way.  The tricky parts are the "5 seconds" and "150 million degrees Celsius".  I'd say the electrical storage part is a moot point since the conversion process from heat to electricity is going to spread the power out to a manageable level.  Going back to the Tesla example, a level 3 supercharger can handle 140kW, which would be enough to transfer 59MJ in ~7 minutes.  With commonly envisioned thermal conversion processes, that is a very reasonable expectation.

Comment: Film capacitors. Large ones.

Answer (score 2):

To summarize the comments into an actual answer:

- What theoretically would be required to capture that energy and transmit it into storage?

This is thermal energy, so it is already captured and stored in the form of making something hot.  To convert that energy you would use water or another fluid, heat it up, and then boil it to move a turbine.  That turbine would then convert a fraction of the energy into electrical power and dissipate the rest as waste heat.

- What theoretical 'battery' could be made to handle such enormous amounts so fast?

Batteries cannot store thermal energy.  Further, by power plant standards, this is actually very little energy.  A typical large power plants might generate on the order of 500 times more thermal power and do so continuously, not just for a few seconds.  To build a practical power plant, you would want to scale up that power output by a few orders of magnitude such that you had a more usable quantity of power, and find a way to produce it continuously so that you had a more usable quantity of energy.  Once that is achieved, you heat up water and turn a generator just like any other power plant.

- If it were possible, could it then be drained off slowly for use, say over a month or two?

59 MJ is roughly the thermal energy in the gasoline tank of my lawn mower, and you could only capture a fraction of it as usable electrical energy.  Taking such a small amount of energy and using it over such a long period of time would only give you a few watts of power, but yes you could do that with a battery pack or possibly by running your generator gradually to produce the energy over a longer time period.